# Cannot select CustomTraceListener with "Type Selector" window in Enterprise Library 4.1

Tags: types, enterprise-library, selector, tracelistener

i created a Custom Trace Liastener inside a class library :

```
namespace SendMailTraceListener
{
    [ConfigurationElementType(typeof(CustomTraceListenerData))]
    public class SendEmailTraceListener : CustomTraceListener
    {

        public override void Write(string message)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
     }
}
```

it compiles fine.

Then, in Enterprise Library 4.1, i created new Custom TraceListener and pushed the "Type" button in the TraceListener properties to open the "Type selector" window.

i pushed "Load from file" button and browsed to the Custom Trace Listener class library and chose the dll from the Bin->Debug folder of the class library.

but it doesn't work, i get the message:

"There were no types found in the assembly 'SendMailTraceListener' that implement or inherit from the base type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.CustomTraceListener'."

Why ? !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

It is a Visual Studio 2008 bug.

when i used the Enterprise Library Configuration application itself ( not the VS2008  -right clicking on the config file and choosing "Edit Enterprise Library Configuration" ) , it works!

Comment: @Rodniko, you should accept your answer if it is the solution.